# How to make a POST call to Microsoft Graph in SPFx (using MSGraphClient)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

I have difficulties to find code samples of POST calls, using the MSGraphClient.

The only one I find is using the already deprecated graphHTTPClient ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/call-microsoft-graph-using-graphhttpclient ):

I wonder what would be the proper way to create an Office 365 Group using the modern MSGraphClient syntax; how do I pass the JSON Request body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MSGraphClient` is still in preview and will not work in production tenants as of writing this. Have tested the below the code and it works in Developer tenant.

Add the below import statement:

```
import { MSGraphClient } from "@microsoft/sp-client-preview";
import { Group } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types";
```

To create a group, make a POST request to the graph groups endpoint as below:

```
const graphClient : MSGraphClient = this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey)

const group : Group = {
        displayName: "Sample test group",
        description: "Group description",
        groupTypes: [
            "Unified"
        ],
        mailEnabled: true,
        mailNickname: "TestGroup",
        securityEnabled: true
    };


graphClient
.api("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/")
.post(group)
.then((groupResponse) => {
    console.log(groupResponse);        
});
```

Have added the below npm package:

```
npm install @microsoft/microsoft-graph-types --save-dev
```

Reference - [Use MS Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph)

Github sample - [API Scopes](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/dev/tutorials/api-scopes)

Comment: I used the same approach but it is giving error as **Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"owners@odata.bind"' does not exist in type 'Group'**. when I'm trying to add owner of group explicitly. const groups : Group = { "description": ProName + " Office 365 Group", "displayName": ProName + "_Team", "groupTypes": [ "Unified" ], "mailEnabled": false, "mailNickname": ProName + "_Team", "securityEnabled": false, "owners@odata.bind": HBCAdminCol }; How I can add owner to it using MSGraphClient as it was working finely with graphHttpClient.

Comment: Instead of `owners@odata.bind`, can you try with `owners: "HBCAdminCol@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"` or `owners: ["HBCAdminCol@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"]` and check ?

Answer (score 2):

This should help you get started. Here I'm registering a webhook

```
const graphClient = this.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey)
const future: Date = new Date(Date.now() + 4320 * 60);
const body: object = {
    changeType: "created",
    notificationUrl: "mywebhookurl",
    resource: "me/messages",
    expirationDateTime: future.toISOString(),
    clientState: "SecretClientState"
  };
await graphClient.api(`subscriptions`).post(body);
```

Comment: you're welcome! upvote if you like the answers :)